# Update Azure Event Grid function subscription with dead-letter storage

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have successfully created an event trigger on storage blob creation, on a storage account called `receivingtestwesteurope`, under resource group `omni-test`, which is received via a function called `ValidateMetadata`. I created this via the portal GUI. However I now want to add deadletter/retry policies, which can only be done via the CLI.

The working trigger is like this:

```
{
    "destination": {
      "endpointBaseUrl": "https://omnireceivingprocesstest.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig",
      "endpointType": "WebHook",
      "endpointUrl": null
    },
    "filter": {
      "includedEventTypes": [
        "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
      ],
      "isSubjectCaseSensitive": null,
      "subjectBeginsWith": "/blobServices/default/containers/snapshots/blobs/",
      "subjectEndsWith": ".png"
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/fa6409ab-1234-1234-1234-85dd2b3ceab4/resourceGroups/omni-test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/StorageAccounts/receivingtestwesteurope/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/png",
    "labels": [
      ""
    ],
    "name": "png",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "omni-test",
    "topic": "/subscriptions/fa6409ab-1234-1234-1234-85dd2b3ceab4/resourceGroups/omni-test/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/receivingtestwesteurope",
    "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions"
}
```

First I thought I could update the existing event with a deadletter queue:

```
az eventgrid event-subscription update --name png --deadletter-endpoint receivingtestwesteurope/blobServices/default/containers/eventgrid
```

Which returns:

> az: error: unrecognized arguments: --deadletter-endpoint
>   receivingtestwesteurope/blobServices/default/containers/eventgrid

Then I tried via REST Patch:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/eventsubscriptions/update

- scope: `/subscriptions/fa6409ab-1234-1234-1234-85dd2b3ceab4/resourceGroups/omni-test/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/receivingtestwesteurope`
- eventSubscriptionName: `png`
- api-version: `2018-05-01-preview`

Body:

```
"deadletterdestination": {
  "endpointType": "StorageBlob",
  "properties": {
    "blobContainerName": "eventgrid",
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/fa6409ab-1234-1234-1234-85dd2b3ceab4/resourceGroups/omni-test/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/receivingtestwesteurope"
  }}
```

Which returns

> "Model state is invalid."

===================

**Final working solution:**

```
{
    "deadletterdestination": {
        "endpointType": "StorageBlob",
        "properties": {
            "blobContainerName": "eventgrid",
            "resourceId": "/subscriptions/fa6409ab-1234-1234-1234-85dd2b3ceab4/resourceGroups/omni-test/providers/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/receivingtestwesteurope"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. There is a bad news for dead-lettering, such as a turning-off  dead-lettering. I have mentioned many times to MS Event Grid team and the response is the following, you can not use a Patch, you have to use multiple requests such as GET subscription, Get full destinationEndpointUrl and then recreating this event subscription without the deadLetterDestination property using a PUT request. I think, this is a bug. In other words, we can NOT use a simple removing property such as "deadletterdestination":null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at [Manage Event Grid delivery settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery), where in details is described turning-on a dead-lettering. Note, you have to install an eventgrid extension

*az extension add --name eventgrid*

also, you can use a REST API for updating your event subscription for dead-lettering.

besides that, I have just released my tinny tool [Azure Event Grid Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester) for helping with an Azure Event Grid model on the local machine.

**Update:**

The following is a *deadletterdestination* property:

```
"deadletterdestination": {
  "endpointType": "StorageBlob",
  "properties": {
    "blobContainerName": "{containerName}",
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resgroup}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccount}"
   }
 }
```

you can use the [Event Subscriptions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/eventsubscriptions/update) (REST API PATCH) with the above property. Note, that the *api-version=2018-05-01-preview* must be used.

Comment: The commands I'm having trouble with are from the first link you provided

Comment: I have just installed on my azure portal cloud shell (>_) this eventgrid extension. The response is: The installed extension 'eventgrid' is in preview., so did you have the problem with this installation?

Comment: Hi, your update looks really useful. I feel this is close, I updated my question with my progress. I ran the REST patch via the online editor

Comment: the patch (update) is working only for properties, so the json body must be in the format: {  "deadletterdestination": { …. }, "filter": {}, "labels":[ ], ...    } , please have a look at my Update, I am going to edit it. Thanks

Comment: The EventSubscriptions REST API (including `Update` method) url (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/eventsubscriptions/update) is dead (404). Anyone know what the updated URL is?